# Notify bar plugin not showing up

Tags: plugins

I'm a beginner user and have downloaded the [Notify Bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/notify-bar/) and activated it, but it's not showing on the website.  I'm not able to work in code but any help appreciated.

Comment: Does the edit I've done links to the correct plugin? :::: Always read the full plugin *Description*, *Installation* and *FAQ* sections before installing. [Item 3](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/notify-bar/installation/) explains the modifications you need to do. Otherwise, follow @anu suggestion.

Comment: If it isn't working you may need to "work in code". Please provide some [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't work with code, then you probably can't use Notify Bar, as it needs a change to the templates. Try looking for another notification plugin, there are plenty in the Plugin Repository.